# SIP and RTP implementation in C++

Tags: c++, sip, network-protocols, rtp

Are there reliable open source libraries written in c++ to implement SIP and RTP protocols ? If not , is it easy to implement them using boost.asio ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For SIP take a look at [PJSIP](http://www.pjsip.org/); for RTP take a look at [JRTPLIB](http://research.edm.uhasselt.be/~jori/page/index.php?n=CS.Jrtplib)

Comment: PJSIP also implements RTP, see e.g. https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/PJSIP-Datasheet

Answer (score 0):

For RTP you could consider [ccRTP](https://www.gnu.org/software/ccrtp/) from the GNU Project.